# implicit parameters and generic types

Tags: scala, implicit-parameters

i'm trying to understand the behavior of the compiler in this situation

```
object ImplicitTest extends App {

  def foo[T](implicit x: (String => T)): T = ???

  implicit val bar = (x: String) => x.toInt

  foo
}
```

the code above does not compile and gives the following error:

> ambiguous implicit values: both method $conforms in object Predef of
>   type [A]⇒ <:<[A,A] and value bar in object ImplicitTest of type ⇒ String ⇒
>   Int match expected type String ⇒ T

as the error says my implicit value is conflicting with another implicit defined in Predef... based on this it seems there is no way to declare an implicit parameter to a function converting a value from a known type to an unknown (generic) type.

Is this due to some technical limitation on the compiler or is just the way it is supposed to work, and i'm violating some constraints i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not providing a type parameter to `foo` when you call it (and there is no other way to infer it, for the following reason), so the compiler is having trouble finding the right one, and the right implicit.

You have the implicit `bar: String => Int` in scope, but you *also* have implicits in `Predef` that create instances of `=:=` and `<:<` which both extend `A => B`, and create implicit `String => A`s. The compiler is looking for *some* implicit function `String => T` for `foo`, but it's not sure which one, and you have multiple in scope. `bar` will not take precedence because you haven't specified the specific `String => T` it's looking for.

This will work:

```
def foo[T](implicit x: (String => T)): T = ???

implicit val bar = (x: String) => x.toInt

foo[Int]
```

Comment: got it, so it was about type inference.. now that i think of it makes perfect sense, the compiler has not enough information to narrow down the generic T to a concrete type so that "bar" would take precedence... thanks for the answer, now all makes sense again :)